# MariaDB multiple identical row even when using REPEATABLE READ transaction

Tags: transactions, locking, mariadb, isolation-level

I have a nodejs web service with MariaDB server and about 500 daily active users in my app.

In my code, I use a transaction like below:

```
START TRANSACTION

-- select to find out the existence of a row --
-- if the row doesn't exist, a new row inserted --

COMMIT
```

this transaction should result in no duplicate row inserted but it does not.
I think this occurs when 2 requests with different sessions arrives at the same time and see that the row doesn't exist and then both sessions insert it.

The MariaDB transaction isolation-level are REPEATABLE-READ.

Is this because of REPEATABLE READ isolation-level?

How to exclusivly lock reads and writes when another session might read the same row?

Answer (score 0):

Instead, do one of these, either of which is 'atomic' and does not need `BEGIN/COMMIT` around it unless there are other statements that belong in the same transaction:

```
INSERT IGNORE ...;

INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...;
```

To explain what is wrong with our code:  You should have had `FOR UPDATE` on the `SELECT`.